# Sort by post word count in admin area

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I have a custom post type called `species` which consists of a number of `meta_fields`.

Ideally, what I'd like, is a word count for each `species profile` (that's just the term I use for a singular post of type `species`).

So, for example, when you click the `Species` menu in the back-end, you can see a list of all the species profiles (paginated, as WordPress does) with information about how many words are in each `species profile` and to be able to sort by that `ASC`/`DESC`.

If I was doing this outside of the back-end area I'd probably do the following:

- Retrieve all of the data for the specific `Post_ID`
- `strip_tags` the data (and WP's shortcode tags)
- Put it all in a big string
- Use `$array = explode( " ", $string )` to create a large array
- Get the word count from `sizeof( $array )`

Question is, how can I put this into the WordPress admin area for this post type? And how do I make it sortable?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to hook save_post and save the count for each post to a meta field. It's not feasible to do the calculation when the back end is loaded, every post will have to be queried and sorted in memory. Likewise, doing it all in MySQL will require some significant query modification, and still then you won't be able to remove shortcodes and markup from the numbers.

as far as the columns and sort are concerned, there are several answers here on how to do that, start with the Related questions column to the right. Also see [this post by Scribu](http://scribu.net/wordpress/custom-sortable-columns.html) on the subject.